# Having Trouble Installing iPython

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, installation

Well, my python was working perfectly.  All of a sudden, it gave me this:

```
-bash: ipython: command not found
```

I did play around with some bash profiles, but I'm a beginner so I don't really know what I did.  I really need help.

Anyway, now I tried doing this and got this:

```
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~ eddylopez-torres$ pip install ipython
-bash: pip: command not found
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~ eddylopez-torres$ sudo python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~ eddylopez-torres$ sudo python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~ eddylopez-torres$ cd Downloads/
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:Downloads eddylopez-torres$ cd LabTools-0.2.2
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:LabTools-0.2.2 eddylopez-torres$ python setup.py install
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing LabTools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to LabTools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to LabTools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'LabTools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'LabTools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg
error: could not create 'build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg': Permission denied
```

I tried following this post:

> Chances are that at one point you tried running python setup.py under sudo and now have a dist directory belonging to root. 
>   Clear out the existing dist subdirectory in your build directory and rerun:

```
sudo rm -rf ./dist
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install
```

> If you then get permission errors in the final install step, you may need to run the install step under sudo:

```
sudo bash
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
/path/to/same/python2.7 setup.py install
exit
```

> but it's probably better to not do that if you don't have to.

But as you can see...it didn't go as planned:

```
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:LabTools-0.2.2 eddylopez-torres$ sudo rm -rf ./dist ARCHFLAGS='arch x86_64' python setup.py install
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:LabTools-0.2.2 eddylopez-torres$ ipython
-bash: ipython: command not found
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:LabTools-0.2.2 eddylopez-torres$ sudo rm -rf ./dist
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:LabTools-0.2.2 eddylopez-torres$ ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:LabTools-0.2.2 eddylopez-torres$ sudo bash
root@Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~/Downloads/LabTools-0.2.2# export ARCHFLAGS=' arch x86_64'root@Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~/Downloads/LabTools-0.2.2# /path/to/same/python2.7 setup.py install
bash: /path/to/same/python2.7: No such file or directory
root@Eddy-Lopez-Torres-Computer:~/Downloads/LabTools-0.2.2# exit
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks sooooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

The errors in your last quoted terminal session were caused by this command:

```
sudo rm -rf ./dist ARCHFLAGS='arch x86_64' python setup.py install
```

The `-r` option tells `rm` to recursively delete all listed files.  The `-f` option tells it to force deleting them.  Running the command as `sudo` means that `rm` has permission to delete anything.  So you can see, using `sudo rm -rf` is something that should be done with *utmost care*.

Your command deleted the following things:

- `./dist` - the folder you were probably looking to delete
- `ARCHFLAGS='arch x86_64'` - the next item in the command line.  This probably wasn't a file, but `-f` shuts up `rm`'s warnings about files that don't exist.
- `python` - thankfully, the real Python program is not stored in the directory you were working.  If it had been, it would have been deleted!
- `setup.py` - deleted (and you did not intend to do so)
- `install` - probably is not a file in this directory either.

Since `setup.py` was deleted, when you attempted to run `ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install`, it failed with the first `no such file or directory`.

Then, you copied and pasted the command `/path/to/same/python2.7 setup.py install`.  However, the command was not meant to be copied and pasted -- the path `/path/to/same/python2.7` was meant to be replaced with whatever the path to *your* Python installation was (probably `/usr/bin/python2.7`, but you can find it using the command `which python2` or `which python`).

Your installation won't work anymore, since you deleted the `setup.py` file.  You'll have to get a new copy of it from where you got the first one.  Once you do that, maybe it will work.

Oh, by the way, you really should *never* copy and paste commands without knowing *exactly* what they do (**especially** if they contain `sudo`).  When you do that, you're giving complete control over your computer to somebody you have no reason to trust.  If you don't understand the command, **start Googling**.  Most commands can be figured out with a little bit of research.

Comment: Also, if all you want to do is install IPython, this should do the trick: `sudo pip install ipython`.  Of course, make sure you know what that does before you run it ;)